# Aliases in OSX Terminal, unable to find PhpStorm 2 Application

Tags: macos, shell, command-line

I have used this "ea" alias with previous versions of PhpStorm but since the change to "PhpStorm 2" it doesn't work anymore, any suggestions?

My current setting is:

```
alias phpstorm="PhpStorm 2"
alias ea='open -a phpstorm ~/ .aliases'
```

The terminal output is:

```
// Calling the alias
ea

// Output error
Unable to find application named 'phpstorm'
```

P.S. Even if I escape the name like this, it doesn't find the application:

```
alias phpstorm="PhpStorm\ 2"
```

Comment: try using the `Phpstorm\ 2` directly in ea, i think aliases can't contain other aliases

Comment: Using it directly it works, but that's not the trick :-) because I wanna re-use the alias and have to change it once eventually.

Comment: `open` is not a shell command, and therefore unaware of shell aliases.

Comment: @robertklep in mac os `open` is a shell command https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html

Comment: @mvrma by "shell command" I mean "a command that is implemented by the shell".

Comment: @robertklep i can't verify that right now, but i don't think that's relevant. it's just c code in the end, i'm sure you can interact with shell aliases

Comment: @mvrma an alias gets expanded by the shell when it's used as if it's a regular command, not (as in this case) as an argument to another command.

Comment: @robertklep that sounds reasonable, but i'll try it nonetheless.

Comment: So is there a workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try: open -a application_name

Keep in mind that 'PhpStorm 2' is not a valid binary in your PATH. With '-a' you are telling to 'open' look for an application with that name, which 'Phpstorm 2' is.

Answer (score 0):

This works now for me :)

```
alias ps2="open -a PhpStorm\ 2"

alias ea='ps2 .aliases'
```